# Where to define the MetaMask window.ethereum.on Listener

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, javascript, nodejs

I have tried to include the `window.ethereum.on` listener to detect account changes in MetaMask, in my `mounted () {}` method. When the listener is triggered, it itself triggers the `location.reload()` method.

When including this listener and `location.reload()` method in my `mounted () {}` method, it is triggered in an infinite loop, the `location.reload()` method being infinitely re-triggered at every reload. However, if I include the listener outside the mounted method, it is never called. Where should the listener be defined?

```
 mounted () {
   ...
   window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
     ...
     window.location.reload(true)
   })
 }
```

Thank you. J

Comment: did anyone here figure this out? In general I am struggling to understand where these listeners should be placed. It works inside of render() and componentDidMount...sort of. But I suspect this is not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  I tried putting that listener inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
    window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts){
    ...
       ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
       //function to perform on account change
       })
    })
       
})
```

This seems to prevent the call to the listener callback function every time you load the page.  Let me know if you find the same.